# Using withMessageKey for custom validation messages in Aurelia

Tags: aurelia

I have an Aurelia app and I am using the Aurelia validation tool for client-side validation.  I want to use the `validationMessages` dictionary to define a list of custom validation messages to use throughout my app using `withMessageKey` like so:

```
import {validationMessages} from 'aurelia-validation';

validationMessages['customMessage1'] = `My first custom message`; 
validationMessages['customMessage2'] = `My second custom message`;
```

And then when I set the validation rules on the class:

```
import { ValidationRules } from "aurelia-validation";

export class SampleObject {
    text1;
    text2; 

    constructor() {
        ValidationRules
            .ensure(a => a.text1)
                .required()
                    .then().satisfies(x => x.trim() === x)
                    .withMessageKey('customMessage1')
            .ensure(a => a.text2)
            .satisfies( x => x.length > 5)
                .withMessageKey('customMessage2')
            .on(this);
    }
};
```

The validation works, but the custom messages do not show up, the standard ones do.  If I use `withMessage('My first custom message')` for example instead, then it does work, but I want to keep all of my custom messages in one place for use throughout the app.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In which file do you define your custom messages? Are you sure that file is loaded? Could you try to put the custom messages to the same file where you declare your validation rules?

Comment: I've tried putting the custom messages in a separate file, in the same file as the class (but outside the class), and inside the view model in which the class is used.  None of these work.  I was able to get it to work if I include the validation messages inside the class, but this is not really what I am looking for because I want to use them throughout the app

Comment: Can you try also importing the `validationMessages` in your class?  Change your first line in the class to `import { ValidationRules, validationMessages } from "aurelia-validation";`

Comment: I was able to get it working by putting my custom `validationMessages` in the constructor of my `app.js`.  This is not exactly clean, so I still need to think of a better way to ensure the messages are loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution:

I created a class which contains my custom messages in the constructor:

```
import { validationMessages } from 'aurelia-validation';

export class CustomValidationMessages {
    constructor() {
        validationMessages['customMessage1'] = `My first custom message`; 
        validationMessages['customMessage2'] = `My second custom message`;
    }
}
```

Then, I inject it into my `app.js`:

```
import { inject } from 'aurelia-framework';
import { CustomValidationMessages } from "resources/utils/validation-messages";

@inject( CustomValidationMessages )
export class App {
    constructor() {
    }
    configureRouter(config, router) {
        .....
    }
}
```

And I am able to use `customMessage1` and `customMessage2` everywhere throughout my app.  I'm not sure this is the best way to do this, but it works.